# Жизненый цикл активностей

Tags: java, android, activity

Не буду рассписывать почему и как, формулировка вопроса такова: есть две активности A и B, почему после интента активности A в активность B, активность проходит круг : onPause - onResume - onStop. По идеи должно же onPause - onStop - onDestroy... 
onResume, я так понимаю, должен отробатывать, когда я активность сворачиваю, а не когда я ухожу из нее полностью
Код мало, что даст, но на всякий:

```
  public void onClickClick(MenuItem item) {

    //Navigation.findNavController(item.getActionView()).navigate(R.id.nav_home);

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit_to_auth) {
        StateApp.setAuthUser(false);
        System.out.println("Кнопка выход, boolean перед выходом = " + StateApp.isAuthUser());
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AuthenticationActivity.class));

    }
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {  // так правильно, но я не могу понять, почему onPause ,а не onStop
    super.onPause();
    loadState();

}
void loadState(){
    // Авторизирован ли пользователь?
    System.out.println("onStop() , boolean перед выходом ( первая ) = " + StateApp.isAuthUser() );
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(StateApp.getAppPreferences(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(StateApp.getAppPreferencesAuthBooleanCounter(),StateApp.isAuthUser());
    editor.apply();
    System.out.println("onStop() , boolean перед выходом = " + StateApp.isAuthUser() );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов **A**.onPause означает, что **A** теряет фокус и переходит в состояние Paused. Затем создается (onCreate), отображается (onStart) и получает фокус (onResume) **B**. Затем перестает быть видно (onStop) **A**. Обратите внимание, что не вызывается onDestroy для **A**, а значит, оно не уничтожается. **A** остается в памяти, в состоянии Stopped. А **B** – находится в состоянии Resumed. Его видно и оно в фокусе, с ним можно взаимодействовать.

[Здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/61-urok-24-activity-lifecycle-primer-smeny-sostojanij-s-dvumja-activity.html) более подробно можно почитать про работу ЖЦ Активити.

Comment: Ваш ответ правильный, спасибо вам , но у меня ошибка была в другом :)

Comment: Ну так вы ж вопрос задали то как?)

Comment: Просто я косяк)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Сергея верен, но если мы используем динамический фрагмент ( как собственно мой, то действовать надо по другому[image: Полный жизненый цикл]

Ответ Сергея объяснил, почему у меня вызывался onResume(), и действительно, он прав, но при выходе из фрагмента, нужно реализовывать метод onDestroyView(), если мы используем динамический фрагмент

Comment: Ваш вопрос был про ЖЦ Activity, а не Fragment

Comment: Cогласен, просто решил поделиться,мб кому пригодиться